# Scan table to find certain value in column, then return previous values of another column Python

Tags: python, pandas

Using python, from a table like this:

```
A  B  C
0  1  5
1  1  8
2  1  5
3  1  4
4  1  5
5  5  10
6  5  9
7  1  5
8  1  4
9  1  5
10 5  4
```

How can I create a function that scans through to find all ‘B’ values = 5, and then return the previous 4 ‘C’ values, where ‘B’ = 1? If there are only 3 ‘B’ = 1, then just return 3.

After the first ‘B’ = 5, I need an output of 8, 5, 4, 5. The second ‘B’ = 5 should return nothing because it doesn’t have any ‘B’ = 1 immediately preceding it. The third ‘B’ = 5 needs to return 5, 4, 5. This should be be written into a completely new dataset with a space between every new ‘B’ = 5 value, looking like this:

```
8
5
4
5

5
4
5
```

Comment: please post your desired data set

Comment: I'm very confused in regards to the logic here. Is this all ONE function? and where does that output of 8545 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
`loc` + `groupby` + `tail` -

```
i = df.B.eq(5).cumsum()
df.loc[df.B == 1, 'C'].groupby(i, group_keys=False).tail(4)

1    8
2    5
3    4
4    5
7    5
8    4
9    5
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 2**
`groupby` + `apply`.

```
v = df.B.groupby(i, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x[x == 1].iloc[-4:]).index    
df.loc[v, 'C']

1    8
2    5
3    4
4    5
7    5
8    4
9    5
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind that cosmetic change... ;-)